# How can I generate a random IP address from a list of IP ranges in Python?

Tags: python

How can I generate a random IP address from a list of IP ranges in Python?

I tried to create a list of ip address using ipaddress module then make it random.

```py
ipRanges = [
    "103.112.2.0/24"
]
network = ipaddress.IPv4Network(random.choice(ipRanges))
ip= random.choice(list(network))
```

this is my current code. it worked, But it uses a many RAM because it needs to be stored in a list
Any better ways?

Comment: Please show your and error message.

Comment: Please show us your code with the desired output/input.

Comment: Would be much efficient if you parse the IP in binary and then generate random IP

Answer (score 5):

You can use the netmask and the address from the IPNetwork object to construct an IP address within the range:

```
import ipaddress
import random

# Pick a CIDR block to use
ipRanges = [
    "103.112.2.0/24",
    "1.0.0.0/8",
]
network = ipaddress.IPv4Network(random.choice(ipRanges))

# Get the netmask and address as a list of bytes
netmask = network.netmask.packed
address = network.network_address.packed

# Operate on each byte of the address
picked = b''
for netmask_byte, address_byte in zip(netmask, address):
    # Pick a random value
    val = random.randint(0, 255)
    # Or in the random bits not in the netmask with the bits in the address in the netmask
    picked += bytes([((255 ^ netmask_byte) & random.randint(0, 255)) | address_byte])
# Turn the result into an IP address
picked = ipaddress.IPv4Address(picked)

print(picked)
```

Answer (score 4):

Instead of generating all the possible IPs and picking one, you should just threat the IP as 32-bit integer and use the network address as the fixed most significant bits and generate a random host part.

```
import ipaddress, random, struct

def random_ip(network):
    network = ipaddress.IPv4Network(network)
    network_int, = struct.unpack("!I", network.network_address.packed) # make network address into an integer
    rand_bits = network.max_prefixlen - network.prefixlen # calculate the needed bits for the host part
    rand_host_int = random.randint(0, 2**rand_bits - 1) # generate random host part
    ip_address = ipaddress.IPv4Address(network_int + rand_host_int) # combine the parts 
    return ip_address.exploded
```

This gives you:

```
>>> for _ in range(4):
    print(random_ip("103.112.2.0/24"))

103.112.2.143
103.112.2.120
103.112.2.75
103.112.2.59

>>> for _ in range(4):
    print(random_ip("103.112.164.0/22"))

103.112.165.120
103.112.164.219
103.112.165.159
103.112.166.232

>>> for _ in range(4):
    print(random_ip("103.112.164.0/255.255.252.0"))

103.112.165.17
103.112.165.210
103.112.167.184
103.112.166.171

>>> for _ in range(4):
    print(random_ip("0.0.0.0/0"))

115.231.216.55
252.123.19.92
218.198.69.183
179.73.234.254
```

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming you're only interested in IPv4 addresses, since that's what you show in your example.  The answer gets more complicated if you need to do IPv6 addresses too.

Making random selections will be much easier if you can convert the range of IP addresses into a range of integers.  Fortunately `ipaddress` makes this simple even if it's not straightforward.

```
import ipaddress
import struct

def ip_range(addr_spec):
    ip = ipaddress.ip_network(addr_spec)
    base = struct.unpack('>I', ip.network_address.packed)[0]
    mask = struct.unpack('>I', ip.netmask.packed)[0]
    extent = 0x100000000 - mask
    return range(base, base+extent)
```

So now you can convert your list into something easier to work with:

```
ranges = [ip_range(spec) for spec in ipRanges]
```

You probably want each IP address to be equally likely to be chosen, so you need to make a table of weights corresponding to the size of each range.

```
weights = [len(r) for r in ranges]
```

From here the process is simple.  First you choose a range at random, then randomly select a specific address within the range.

```
import random

rng = random.choices(ranges, weights=weights)[0]
ip_int = random.choice(rng)
ip_addr = ipaddress.ip_address(ip_int)
```

The reason this is more efficient is that starting with Python 3, `range` returns a range object rather than a list.  This object is hyper-optimized; all it stores is the parameters that were passed in, and a little simple math is all that's required to implement the interface - there's no need to precompute all the values and hold them in memory.  For example, `len(range)` is roughly `(stop - start) // step`.  `range[i]` is roughly `start + i * step`.  Obviously the full implementation is a little more complex than that, but the memory usage and time complexity are still O(1).

Comment: Is there a way to also randomly generate a prefixlen and output the complete IP in CIDR notation e.g. 172.31.254.115/29 ?

Comment: @luckman212 CIDR isn't used for single IP addresses, only ranges.  You can get the 4 octet dot notation with `str(ip_addr)`.

Answer (score 0):

how about this

```
>>> import random
>>> ".".join(str(random.randint(0,255)) for _ in range(4))
'102.131.173.132'
>>> ".".join(str(random.randint(0,255)) for _ in range(4))
'13.58.135.8'
>>> ".".join(str(random.randint(0,255)) for _ in range(4))
'60.224.20.244'
>>>
```

The above can be specialize into a function that take any combination of numbers or a tuple of 2 number (a,b) and in the latter case pick a random number in the interval [a,b], and if less that 4 elements are given fill the missing part with a random number in the range 0-255

```
>>> def random_ip(*parts):
        ip_part=[]
        for p in parts:
            if isinstance(p,int):
                ip_part.append(p)
            else:
                ip_part.append(random.randint(*p))
        while len(ip_part)<4:
            ip_part.append(random.randint(0,255))
        return ".".join(map(str,ip_part))

>>> random_ip(103,112,2,(0,24))
'103.112.2.17'
>>> random_ip(103,112,2,(0,24))
'103.112.2.21'
>>> random_ip(103,112,2,(0,24))
'103.112.2.7'
>>> random_ip(103,112,2,(0,24))
'103.112.2.18'
>>>     
>>> random_ip(103,(100,200),2,(0,24))
'103.184.2.5'
>>> random_ip(103,(100,200),2,(0,24))
'103.149.2.11'
>>> random_ip(103,(100,200),2,(0,24))
'103.161.2.6'

>>> # 103.112.2.0/24
>>> random_ip(103,112,2)
'103.112.2.229'
>>> random_ip(103,112,2)
'103.112.2.91'
>>> random_ip(103,112,2)
'103.112.2.203'
>>> random_ip(103,112,2)
'103.112.2.98'

>>> # 103.112.164.0/22
>>> random_ip(103,112,(164,167))
'103.112.165.78'
>>> random_ip(103,112,(164,167))
'103.112.165.241'
>>> random_ip(103,112,(164,167))
'103.112.167.192'
>>> random_ip(103,112,(164,167))
'103.112.167.25'
>>>
```

Comment: OP wants them from a specific network, not a completely random one.

Comment: @gre_gor how about now?

Comment: Thank you for the code! sorry for the additional question but how can i pass parts by ipv4 network address format: 103.112.2.0/24? really thanks

Comment: `103.112.2.0/24` would be `random_ip(103,112,2,(0,255))` not `random_ip(103,112,2,(0,24))`. And net masks can more complex that that. `103.112.164.0/22` isn't as trivial.

Comment: I'm not familiar with networks protocols, but if its just picking a random number for any of the parts of the ip, this code is a good starting point, and and looking at the output of `ipaddress.IPv4Network("103.112.164.0/22")` looks like it would be `random_ip(103,112,(164,167))`

Comment: OP wants to provide input as CIDR notation, not in parts with ranges. He might even need input such as `103.112.2.0/255.255.255.0` or `103.112.164.0/255.255.252.0`.

Comment: ok thank you! I need to learn more..... really thanks